# Configure Keras backend in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, keras

I am using Jenkins to run a python script on Windowas.

In the script it uses Keras with tensorflow backend (I configured Keras.json). Then I encountered a problem: the Keras in my PyCharm and normal prompt uses Tensorflow backend but uses Theano backend when I run the script in Jenkins.

Normally when running in PyCharm, it uses Tensorflow backend as configured.

[image: Using Tensorflow backend in PyCharm]

as described, when running in Jenkins it used Theano.

[image: But changed into Theano backend in Jenkins]

This is my json config file for keras.

[image: json config file]

I think I need to config something like keras.json again somewhere but I couldn't find it elsewhere. Can anyone help me to properly configure so that I can use keras with Tensorflow backend on Jenkins . Thank you